# Atomically Append object to nested array if object does not already exist within it using StackExchange.Redis and redis-json

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

With `StackExchange.Redis` in `C#` with `redis-json`, how do I atomically add an object to a nested array *but only if* it doesn't already exist within it?

Example JSON document:

```
{
   listId: 4,
   answers: [
       {
           taskId: 4,
           answer: "Hello",
       },
       {
           taskId: 5,
           answer: "World"
       }
   ]
}
```

I want to add the following object to the `answers` property array but *only if* there isn't an object already in the collection with the same `taskId`:

```
{
    taskId: 7,
    answer: "foo"
}
```

And to emphasize once more that this whole operation must be atomic. Both the check for existence and the insertion of the new object must happen in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: "Update if" can be achieved using one of Redis Transaction mechanism.
Did you check ATOMIC / EVAL / FUNCTION?

Comment: Yes. The issue though is that with the nuget packages I'm using for this (StackExchange.Redis & NReJSON), there isn't a way to do both the check & the update in one single atomic action, you have to do the check and the insert separately when using transactions). I did get an answer for this in another forum and it's basically to use the library to execute a custom redis script that does this, because everything in the script itself is atomic. I'll update this question with that answer. I wanted to wait in case somebody knew of an alternative way, but it's looking like there isn't one.

Comment: Yes, that what I meant by EVAL. If you still want to check using transaction you might want to check the NRedisStack client. https://www.nuget.org/packages/NRedisStack

Answer (score 0):

[I asked the same question](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/2235) over on the StackExchange.Redis github page and received an answer with a detailed example. I'm going to copy that answer here for reference (it uses the same ideas that [Guy Korland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593425/guy-korland) mentioned in the comments above).

From [slorello89](https://github.com/slorello89) on github:

> your best bet here is to use a script, scripts allow you to atomically use the intermediary results from you commands. Use a JSON.GET to determine whether the path exists or not e.g. JSON.GET test '$.answers.*[?(@.answer=="foo" && @.taskId==7)]' - will find that exact item that matches that pattern, then you can use an JSON.ARRAPPEND to add the item. So in your example:

```
eval 'local res = redis.call("JSON.GET", "test","$.answers.*[?(@.answer==\"foo\" && @.taskId==7)]") if res == "[]" then redis.call("JSON.ARRAPPEND", "test", "$.answers", "{\"answer\":\"foo\", \"taskId\":7}") return true else return false end' 0
```

> will do exactly what you want to do here on exactly that key. In StackExchange.Redis parlance, you can use a prepared script:

```
var script = @"
    local res = redis.call(""JSON.GET"", @key,""$.answers.*[(@.answer==\"""".. @answer.. ""\"" && @.taskId=="" .. @answerId .. "")]"") 
if res == ""[]"" then
    redis.call(""JSON.ARRAPPEND"", @key, ""$.answers"", ""{\""answer\"":\""""..@answer.. ""\"", \""taskId\"":"" .. @answerId .. ""}"") 
    return true 
end
return false";

var preparedScript = LuaScript.Prepare(script);
var res = muxer.GetDatabase().ScriptEvaluate(preparedScript, new {answer="foo",answerId="7", key});
Console.WriteLine(res.ToString());
res = muxer.GetDatabase().ScriptEvaluate(preparedScript, new {answer="foo",answerId="7", key});
Console.WriteLine(res.ToString());
```

> to achieve the same result.